# How do I make this php code a dropdown menu in html?

Tags: php, html, sql-server-2008

This is what my php code looks like:

```
<html>

Client list:<br><br>

<?php
$serverName = "NEPTUNE\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"tcd", "UID"=>"tcd", "PWD"=>"technician");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);
if( $conn === false ) {
die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
}

$sql = "SELECT client_name FROM client";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
echo $row[0]."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>

</html>
```

This returns a successful query.  How do I select one of the query options from a drop down menu using the select tag in HTML?

Comment: change echo .. to the html for a select? nor really sure what you need here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's nothing wrong with the fetching, just combine it with HTML select + option tags as you normally would do

```
<html>

Client list:<br><br>

<?php

$serverName = "NEPTUNE\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"tcd", "UID"=>"tcd", "PWD"=>"technician");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);
if( $conn === false ) {
die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
}

$sql = "SELECT client_name FROM client";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
?>

<select name="whatever">
    <?php while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>

<?php sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt); ?>

</html>
```

Note: Just make sure you wrap this in a form (with the usual, form method post / get, buttons, etc.). The semantics is yours to decide.